# problem using Aggregate functions with joins

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have two tables Say Table -A and table-B

Table-A having

```
   Userid | Date
 | 
   101       |   15 Aug ,2011 
   102       |   15 Aug ,2011 
   103       |   16 Aug ,2011 
   104       |   16 Aug ,2011 
   105       |   17 Aug ,2011
```

Table -B

```
 Userid(f.k) |  sts 
   101       |   x 
   102       |   y
   101       |   z
   103       |   x
   101       |   y
```

Required output is

Table-C
I want table c output as 
DAte ,Total ,Sts as X,Sts as y, Avg of

```
Date | Total | Sts (if=x) |Sts (if=y) |Avg (Total/2) 

15 Aug| 20   |  15        |5          |10     
16aug | 30   |  22        |8          |15
```

I tried using :

```
select Date, select case when [Tasble-B].Sts='x' Then 0 else 1 END as StsX,select case when [Tasble-B].Sts='Y' Then 0 else 1 END as StsY,Total/2
from
   Table-A
     inner join  Table-B on Table-A.UserID = Table-B.UserID          
     b group by RegDate
```

I am getting Error , I am Stuck with this query.Please Help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Total and Avg are the sum and average of what field/table? What do you mean by Sts (if=x)? What approach have you already tried?

Comment: @paolo : Please read my question now . and Answer

Answer (score 2):

```
select Date, 
       select case when [Tasble-B].Sts='x' Then 0 
                   else 1 
              END as StsX,
       select case when [Tasble-B].Sts='Y' Then 0 
                   else 1 
              END as StsY,
       Total/2 
from Table-A 
  inner join Table-B 
    on Table-A.UserID = Table-B.UserID
b group by RegDate
```

1. You do `group by RegDate` so I assume you should use `RegDate` in the field list instead of `Date` or perhaps `RegDate as Date`.
2. You are missing the total column. You could do that with `count(*) as Total`
3. Your `select case ...` statements should not be select's but `sum(case ...)`
4. `Total/2`, where does `Total` come from? My guess is that you want the average of `StsX` and `StsY` but it could also mean that you want to use the calculated `Total` column and divide that by 2. If that is the case you need to repeat your aggregate statement `count(*)/2` or you could use this entire query as a sub-query and do the calculation using the field `Total` as you already do, `Total/2`.
5. Your table names need to be encapsulated in brackets `[Table-B]`.
6. You have an extra `b` before the `group by` clause. You should remove that.

`

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
select [Date], 
       (SUM(case when B.Sts='x' Then 1 
                   else 0 
              END) + 
       SUM( case when B.Sts='Y' Then 1 
                   else 0 
              END)) AS Total,
       SUM( case when B.Sts='x' Then 1 
                   else 0
              END) AS StsX,
       SUM( case when B.Sts='Y' Then 1 
                   else 0
              END) as StsY,
       (SUM(case when B.Sts='x' Then 1 
                   else 0 
              END) + 
       SUM( case when B.Sts='Y' Then 1 
                   else 0 
              END))
        /2.0 AS Average 
from A 
  inner join B 
    on A.UserID = B.UserID
group by [Date]
```

I tested it with:

```
WITH A (UserId, [Date]) AS ( 
 SELECT 101, '2011-08-15'
 UNION
 SELECT 102, '2011-08-15'
 UNION
 SELECT 103, '2011-08-16'
 UNION
 SELECT 104, '2011-08-16'
 UNION
 SELECT 105, '2011-08-17'
 ),
 B (UserId, sts) AS 
 (
   SELECT 101, 'x'
   UNION 
   SELECT 102, 'y'
   UNION 
   SELECT 101, 'z'
   UNION 
   SELECT 103, 'x'
   UNION 
   SELECT 101, 'y'
)    
select [Date], 
       (SUM(case when B.Sts='x' Then 1 
                   else 0 
              END) + 
       SUM( case when B.Sts='Y' Then 1 
                   else 0 
              END)) AS Total,
       SUM( case when B.Sts='x' Then 1 
                   else 0
              END) AS StsX,
       SUM( case when B.Sts='Y' Then 1 
                   else 0
              END) as StsY,
       (SUM(case when B.Sts='x' Then 1 
                   else 0 
              END) + 
       SUM( case when B.Sts='Y' Then 1 
                   else 0 
              END))
        /2.0 AS Average 
from A 
  inner join B 
    on A.UserID = B.UserID
group by [Date]
```

Comment: @Mikael: nah, just lazy... I think it took you longer to write your answer (and I do hope rakeshwalia takes the time to read it)